# when update courses in EmployeeCourse table exception error generated on savechanges function

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

**Problem**

when i remove all courses for employee from EmployeeCourse table then add again

i have exception error in save changes function

**details**

the logic used in code below for update is to delete all courses from

EmployeeCourse table when click save button

then add courses again to EmployeeCourse table after do changes by add or remove

courses jquery

employee course table have three fields Id,EmployeeId,CourseId(all fields not

allow null)

**in edit [httppost]**

```
var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);
// remove all courses
                foreach (EmployeeCourse eec in emp.EmployeeCourses.ToList())
                {
                    var ec = db.EmployeeCourses.Find(eec.Id);
                    db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
                }
// add courses again
                foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
                {
                    db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });

                }
                db.SaveChanges();
```

**when add course and remove course client side jquery**

@model StudentCourses.Models.EditEmployeeVm

```
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest(".course-item").remove();

        });
        $('#AvailableCourses').change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var text = $("#AvailableCourses option:selected").text();
            var existingCourses = $("input[name='CourseIds']")
                .map(function () { return this.value; }).get();

            if (existingCourses.indexOf(val) === -1) {

                var newItem = $("<div/>").addClass("course-item")
          .append(text + ' <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="' + val + '">Remove </a>');
                newItem.append('<input type="text" name="CourseIds" value="' + val + '" />');

                $("#items").append(newItem);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**to retrieve courses from database in edit view i used code below**

```
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        @Html.HiddenFor(g => g.Id)
        @Html.LabelFor(f => f.Name)
        @Html.DropDownList("AvailableCourses", Model.Courses, "Select")
        <h4>Existing courses</h4>
        <div id="items"></div>
        foreach (var c in Model.ExistingCourses)
        {
            <div class="course-item">
                @c.Name <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="@c.Id">Remove </a>
                <input type="text" name="CourseIds" value="@c.Id" />
            </div>
        }

    }
</div>
```

**model used for that as following**

```
    public class EditEmployeeVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public List<SelectListItem> Courses { get; set; }
        public int[] CourseIds { set; get; }
        public List<CourseVm> ExistingCourses { set; get; }
    }
    public class CourseVm
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string Name { set; get; }
    }
}
```

exception image below

[image]

**update**

You can try as shown below.

```
var emp = db.Employees.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == model.Id);

             // remove all courses
            foreach (EmployeeCourse eec in emp.EmployeeCourses.ToList())
            {
                var ec = db.EmployeeCourses.Find(eec.Id);
                db.EmployeeCourses.Remove(ec);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();//you need this here

            // add courses again
            foreach (var couseid in model.CourseIds)
            {
                db.EmployeeCourses.Add(new EmployeeCourse { CourseId = couseid, EmployeeId = emp.Id });

            }

            db.SaveChanges();
```

until now exception still exist 
my result of code is remove all courses but when add again problem happen
and exception error generated.

**Update 2 :** Model design

[image]

**Update 3**
{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

**details**

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

\"FK_EmployeeCourse_Course\". The conflict occurred in database \"mycourse\",

table \"dbo.Course\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: can you show the `models code` also ? including `PK,FK` references.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/n9e7a063cvmgl7k/model_design_code.jpg

Comment: i attached models above in link and in database employeecourse table have two forign keys EmployeeId,CourseId and two foreign keys not allow null

Comment: can any one help me solving the problem

Comment: {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}

detaile
the error detail exception tell me {"An error occurred while updating the entries.
"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_EmployeeCourse_Course\". The conflict occurred in database \"mycourse\", table \"dbo.Course\", column 'Id'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}